# Unique int from Date

Tags: java, date, calendar

This is general programming, but I'm working in Java.

Given a date `dd-mm-yy` or `dd-mm-yyyy` (e.g. 13-01-2011) I want to convert this into a unique number such that any two dates have a different number. And the year isin't important. So just converting dd-mm into one unique int is acceptable. Does anyone know an algorithm for doing this?

I'm SOrry: I want to be more specific:

The unique numbers should be from 1 to 365 (or 0 to 364), or should break down uniquely modulo 365. (I'm ignoring the case of leap years at the moment).

So concatenating "ddmm" might be a unique 4 digit number. But modulo 365 probably wouldnt be unique.

Comment: What's the functional requirement? The issue needs likely to be solved elsewhere. Otherwise you could as good stick to using `Date` which has by itself already an `equals()` method... Edit: wait, you want to consider two dates with the same `dd-MM` to be equal? (note that `mm` stands for minutes, not months)

Comment: @BalusC: dd-MM is the current requirement. That could change, and I'd hate to be the one to have to modify code that could have just used a two-liner.

Comment: Leap years have 366 days, so modulo 365 the first and last of the year are the same. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you *basically* want to get the day of year? That's not the same as "an unique int from date".

Use [`Calendar#get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_YEAR) (which is 1-based).

```
Date date = getItSomehow();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
int dayOfYear = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
```

As you already admitted, comparing this on leap/non-leap years will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Use the number of days since the beginning of the year.

Comment: Not only is this a bad suggestion, it's hard to implement.

Comment: Implementing is easy, just pull out day of year from a Calendar object.  Would you help me understand why the suggestion is bad?  The asker does not care about year or time.

Comment: It's a lot more work than just using all the data given, even if it's ignored. The data may look better in the end, but I care more about code than data.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was going to do. Its simple enough, but I wondered if there was a faster way, or an inbuilt method that might do it.

Comment: @Stefan: As I read it, this actually answers the question where your answer does not.

Comment: If you use something more specific than day of the year you will have two days that are the same date but due to the time will have different numbers.  Therefore you have to use something like day of the year.  The Calendar object makes that code much simpler than doing it by hand.

Comment: The only real problem I see with this is leap years after Feb 29th. You may need to adjust the year after creating the Calendar and before getting the day of year if you always want f(March 1st, '04) = f(March 1st, '05).

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date().getTime()
```

The number of milliseconds since 1970 should be unique to each date. Just convert the string to a date object and use `getTime()`

```
  DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
  Date date = formatter.format( myInput );
```

Comment: And how about two dates with the same millis?

Comment: Read the question. "So that any two dates have a different number". I'm almost positive that meets the OP's exact requirements.

Comment: I only fail to see how that makes sense. Maybe it's just me :)

Comment: The MS are guaranteed to be unique, and while the OP says the year doesn't matter right now, there's no reason it might not be in the future. In that case, take the easy way out (which in this case is the general-case, as it can be modified to make unique numbers down to dates including milliseconds). Always be mindful of the changing tide of user desires.

Comment: While it's hard to tell for sure, it seems to me that the OP only wants an int value that is distinct for any given month/day combination (since he says the year isn't important). This answer not only factors in the year, but the time of day as well. As such, I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: Fixing the year makes this viable again, and I have a lingering feeling that someone like me will be back in 3-months to turn some abonomination of mappings of JAN->1 into a proper unique identifier generator.

Answer (score 0):

Use unix timestamp see [java.util.Date.getTime()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Update: the OP clarified the question to want a unique value in the range 1-364.  In that case I would convert the date into a `Calendar` object and call `get (Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)` on it - this will return the number of the day within the year, which is exactly what the OP is after it seems.

Original answer:
There about as many ways to do this as there are bits of string.  If you want to be able to use the unique numbers for relative comparison of dates then the most obvious solution is to do what most computers do anyway, namely convert the date into some lowest common denominator, like the number of seconds from a particular epoch.  Java provides ways for doing this with both the `Date` and `Calendar` classes.  If you only care about days and months, you could achieve the same with something like `int v = (month * 120) + day`.  If you don't care about comparisons and just want a unique value, you could come up with a digest of the date using a hashing algorithm of some kind.  In Java you could, for example, take a `String` representation of the date and call `hashCode()` on it.

Comment: month*12+day doesnt work, since multiple dates will have the same number.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think about the numbers carefully but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a unique key, Calendar's hashCode() should do the trick.
Alternately, you can concatenate the two digit month and day, and four digit year.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that others were answering at the same time with the same answers.

Comment: Calendar's hashCode() method is in no way guaranteed to return different values for different dates.